# How to extract several rows from a data frame?

Tags: r, date, dataframe, statistics

Here is the head of my data frame

```
date ,mkt.rf,smb,hml,rf
19990104,-0.0019,0.0021,0.0045,0.00019
19990105,0.011,-0.0088,0.0012,0.00019
19990106,0.021,-0.007,-0.004,0.00019
19990107,-7e-04,0.0046,-0.0022,0.00019
19990108,0.0045,-5e-04,0.0038,0.00019
```

As you can see the structure of the date is not in date format but in int format.I havent tried converting into a date format since this is also complicated for me. I am trying to extract the information from 20180806 to 20180808.

I tried with `df$new_variable <- df[df$year == 20180806]` . I am pretty sure that this is not completely right and I am still missing 2 months

Can you help me do this?

Comment: Have you tried any code to solve your problem? It would be a good idea to try something, and post it here for feedback.

Comment: If you indent the data shown in the question by 4 spaces SO will format it for you properly.

Comment: Thanks G.grothendieck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, date >= 20180806 & date <=20180808)
```

Comment: I am trying to use the subset formula to store the data in a new variable but I am getting an error. This is what Ive done some far:                                             
    new_var <- subset(df1, date >= 20180806 & date <=20180808)

Comment: I have one more question. It seems like the date variable only includes trading days and I am supposed to do the same as above but by including an estimation period of 250 days prior to 20180730. Thus 2 days are missing each week. Is there an efficient way to do this by using the subset function?  Even if I count 250 days back I would be missing almost 2*35 weeks =70 days.

Comment: @alatriste  Did you meant `data >= (20180730 - 250)`

Comment: Yes, but If I do that I would not be including all the dates. The variable is constructed in a way that omits weekends. week one is day: 1,2,3,4,5 then jumps to week two 8,9,10,11,12

Comment: @alatriste  If the date is not present in the 'df1', not clear what you want.  You can create a complete sequence column from `df2 <- data.frame(date = seq(20180730-250, 20180808, by = 1)); merge(df2, df1, by = 'date', all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: 19990114
    19990115
    19990119
    19990120

Comment: The date skipped from 15 to 19

Comment: @alatriste  You would get only the data that is present in your 'df1'  ie. without weekends.  But if the intention is to create some missing rows you can createa a complete sequence andd `merge` as I showed i the earlier comment

Comment: I think using the index column would be better! Thanks though